# To delete usr/bin/X11 on Linux, mainly debian

Tags: debian, filesystems

How safe is it to delete usr/bin/X11 'dummy' item on Linux debian FS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think anything in the current release of Debian relies on the `/usr/bin/X11` symlink; however as a general rule, since `/usr/bin/X11` belongs to a package (`x11-common`), you shouldn’t delete it manually. Everything under `/usr`, apart from `/usr/local`, is supposed to be managed by the package manager.

If you *really* want to delete it, feel free to go ahead and do so; if anything breaks as a result, re-installing `x11-common` will restore the link.